# jQuery Promise Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

After having to change a far bit of my callback syntax in order to accommodate firefox limitations I am running into some weird issues.

Markup + Executing Code

```
function List_Add() {
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var listTitle = 'Quote';
    var propertiesToAdd = [];
    propertiesToAdd.push({
      ID: "Q_ID",
      newval: 1,
    });
    addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd)
      .done(function(items) {
        //Do Heaps of Stuff
      })
      .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error.get_message());
      });

  });
}
```

And the function that is being called to execute this

```
function addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd) {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = ctx.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
  var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var newItem = list.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
  propertiesToAdd.forEach(function(entry) {
    newItem.set_item(entry.ID, entry.newval);
  });
  newItem.update();
  var d = $.Deferred();
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
      d.resolve(true);
      return d.promise();
    },
    function(sender, args) {
      d.reject(args);
      return d.promise();
    });
}
```

The return d.promise while normally outside the functions was causing timing issues with async execution.

The error I am receiving after running this code is thrown the the mark up + execution

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

The values are adding to the lists correctly, so the bulk is working, the .done is not being returned though hence not allowing the execution of the follow up code.

Comment: `addListItems` is not returning anything.

Comment: You're calling `addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd).done().fail()` and that function does not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return d.promise();` needs to go in the outer function, not the inner callbacks. Whatever values return from the inner asynchronously executed callbacks cannot affect the return value of the outer function.

```
function addListItems(listTitle, propertiesToAdd) {
  // ...

  var d = $.Deferred();
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
      d.resolve(true);
    },
    function(sender, args) {
      d.reject(args);
    }
  );
  return d.promise();
}
```